# Portable build of ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, cloudbees

I'd like to build ImageMagick for use with CloudBees. Normally, you would use a package manager like apt, yum, or homebrew to install it. However, on CloudBees you don't have admin access or access to these tools.

I've tried including ImageMagick as part of my build process - however it's linked to use the directory it's built out of "/jenkins/somethingsomething". At runtime it fails to find its libraries. The run-environment is a separate machine, in a directory "/apps/

I've tried building it from source as part of the deploy process, but this causes the deployments to timeout.

Is there any way to build ImageMagick so that it looks in $MAGICK_HOME at runtime instead of binding to a specific, hard-coded path?

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

On development environment, using Jenkins on DEV@cloud, you can try to use it through "curl" command for example. However, on runtime you can only use it, if you customize the stack you want to use.

CloudBees has created stacks for Tomcat, JBoss, Jetty and Glassfish. For example, Tomcat 6 and Tomcat 7 stacks used by CloudBees on runtime are available on GitHub ([here](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat-clickstack)) on different branches.

More information about ClickStacks is available [here](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/ClickStack). Also the way in which you can customize your own stack, [Developing and using your own ClickStacks](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/DevelopingStacks) section.